# How can I make a React-Bootstrap radio group required with HTML validation?

Tags: html, radio-button, react-bootstrap, radio-group

I'm using a pair of [React-Bootstrap radio buttons](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-custom-checkboxes-and-radios) in my app. I need to require that the user make a selection. However, adding `required` as seen here doesn't have the same effect that it would on an HTML radio input.

```
<Form.Check inline label="One" type='radio' required />
<Form.Check inline label="Two" type='radio' required />
```

How can I apply the HTML5 `required` attribute here? I'm looking for basic HTML5 validation, not React validation.

Comment: You can do it on a Form.Control as per https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/#forms-validation-native

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you're directing me to there. I'm looking for basic HTML5 validation, not React validation.

Comment: Didn't look at it that closely but noticed they were using required with Form.Controls and Form.Check but the latter was in a Form.Group, there is also a native html5 validation section using isValid etc- not used this to be honest though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue as you, it's actually very simple and it's a shame they don't specify in the documentation.

Give them all the same name.

```
<Form.Check name="grouped" required inline label="One" type='radio' />
<Form.Check name="grouped" required inline label="Two" type='radio' />
```

Comment: Of course it would be mentioned in the _HTML_ documentation, had I thought to refer to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Set flag in state, default to `true`

```
class HaveAccount extends Component {
  state = {
    flag: true,
  };
  render() {
    const { haveAccount, updateHaveAccount } = this.props;
    const handleChange = (e) => {
      if (this.state.flag)
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, flag: false }));
      updateHaveAccount({ value: e.target.value });
    };
    return (
        <div>
          <Form className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <Form.Group as={Row}>
              <Col sm={{ span: 7, offset: 5 }}>
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="YES"
                  name="haveAccountRadios"
                  value={true}
                  id="haveAccountRadios1"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="NOPE"
                  name="haveAccountRadios"
                  value={false}
                  id="haveAccountRadios2"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <Link
                className={`button button-link ${
                  this.state.flag ? "disabled" : ""
                }`}
                to="/login"
              >
                Next
              </Link>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Step 2:**  I'm conditionally adding className `disabled` based on the flag. Flag only gets updated first time `handleChange` executes.

**Step 3:** Add CSS

```
.disabled {   
  background-color: #ccc;
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```